# Apex Class in Managed Package not showing when scheduling apex job

Tags: apex, managed-package, scheduled-apex

I have installed a managed package for an org under my user, but would like to transfer the owner of scheduled jobs to the admin. In order to do this I will need to delete the existing jobs and create new ones.

However I am unable to find the apex class for the scheduled job when creating a new job when scheduling a new apex job under apex classes; it simply does not show when selecting an apex class to schedule. Are there any permissions I need to consider scheduling an apex job with an apex class from a managed package? I am the system administrator.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only schedule managed package classes yourself that the package's developers have set as `global`. If they are not `global` you cannot see them.

If these are not global, which is what it sounds like, the managed package developers *may* have provided you with another API through which you can request this code to be scheduled. Check their documentation.

If their package includes an post-install script that itself is global you *might* be able to manually run this, constructing it with a null install context, but that rather supposes they wrote it in a way that would allow you to do this (using anonymous Apex). I'm assuming it's the post-install script that actually creates the scheduled jobs otherwise.

A final option would be to grant them "support" access, via your admin account, and have them do this scheduling for you.